# python selenium - webdriver wait until css_Selector visible

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, python-3.5

```
text = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.dbaListing.listing.lastListing > td:nth-child(4) > span').text
```

This is what I want my webdriver to wait for to be located/visible.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`WebDriverWait` with the `visibility_of_element_located` Expected Condition](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dbaListing.listing.lastListing > td:nth-child(4) > span")))
print(element.text)
```

Comment: Thanks buddy that helped !

Answer (score 0):

Pass some wating time to browser until the CSS selector is visible(loaded). You can also pass by implicitly wait function or use

```
 Wait.until()
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Comment: He is just a beginner ad I think not to confuse him by giving a bit complex solution. I know the pain of beginner's

Comment: I am on 99 rep, please upvote, i just want to hit 100 rep. :(

Comment: My point is that your solution isn't complete and doesn't answer the question. It's better to give him a solution that works and maybe he has to study it to understand it but an incomplete solution helps no one.