# Even driver.implicitly_wait is not stopping my Stale Exceptions. What is a way out here?

Tags: python, selenium

I use this function in my Python/Selenium code to keep searching for the element until it is visible.

```
def wait_for_visibility(self, selector, timeout_seconds=10):
    global exceptions
    retries = timeout_seconds
    while retries:
        from selenium.common import exceptions
        try:
            element = self.find_element_by_id(selector)
            if element.is_displayed():
                return element
        except (exceptions.NoSuchElementException,
                exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException):
            if retries <= 0:
                raise
            else:
                pass
        retries = retries - 1
        time.sleep(10)
        self.implicitly_wait(90)
    raise exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException(
        "Element %s not visible despite waiting for %s seconds" % (
            selector, timeout_seconds)
    )
```

There are 5 collapsible window in the page. I am sending the ID of the element to this function to search for it until it is visible. It does its work fine until the 2nd collapse. But for the third collapse I am getting

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed"> stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed
```

How can I stop this from happening? Is there any way to avoid it? I have tried increasing timeout_seconds to 70, 100 etc. I also added a time.sleep(10) and even tried different values of the seconds. But the stale exceptions just won't stop. I am not able to proceed.

Comment: Is this coming from find itself or is this coming when you take action on the object you find?

Comment: From finding itself. It finds just right for the first two collapsible windows. But for the third collapsing, it throws the stale exception. I have also checked the element id and it's perfectly correct as all of the ids are just iterations by in one of the characters.

Comment: And this is being searched using driver or another element at parent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python selenium - webdriver wait until css\_Selector visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708200/python-selenium-webdriver-wait-until-css-selector-visible)

Comment: You've written this long function that is duplicating functionality that already exists in Selenium in a 1-2 liner.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using expected conditions instead.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.visibility_of((By.ID, my_id))
)
```

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits